# find the longest increasing subsequence (LIS)

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given A= {1,4,2,9,7,5,8,2}, find the LIS. Show the filled dynamic programming table and how the solution is found.

My book doesnt cover LIS so im a bit lost on how to start. For the DP table, ive done something similar with Longest Common Subsequences. Any help on how to start this would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a pretty good wikipedia article on this.  You might find what you need to get started there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already plenty of answers on this topic but here's my walkthrough, I view this site as a repository of answers for future posterity and this is just to provide additional insight when I worked through it myself.

The longest Increasing Subsequence (LIS) problem is to find the length of the longest subsequence of a given sequence such that all elements of the 
subsequence are sorted in increasing order. For example, length of LIS for

```
{ 10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80 } is 6 and LIS is {10, 22, 33, 50, 60, 80}.
```

Let `S[pos]` be defined as the smallest integer that ends an increasing sequence of length pos.

Now iterate through every integer X of the input set and do the following:

If X > last element in S, then append X to the end of S. This essentialy means we have found a new largest LIS.

Otherwise find the smallest element in S, which is >= than X, and change it to X. Because S is sorted at any time, the element can be found 
using binary search in log(N).

Total runtime - N integers and a binary search for each of them - N * log(N) = O(N log N)

Now let's do a real example:

Set of integers: 2 6 3 4 1 2 9 5 8

Steps:

```
0. S = {} - Initialize S to the empty set
1. S = {2} - New largest LIS
2. S = {2, 6} - 6 > 2 so append that to S
3. S = {2, 3} - 6 is the smallest element > 3 so replace 6 with 3
4. S = {2, 3, 4} - 4 > 3 so append that to s
5. S = {1, 3, 4} - 2 is the smallest element > 1 so replace 2 with 1
6. S = {1, 2, 4} - 3 is the smallest element > 2 so replace 3 with 2
7. S = {1, 2, 4, 9} - 9 > 4 so append that to S
8. S = {1, 2, 4, 5} - 9 is the smallest element > 5 replace 9 with 5
9. S = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8} - 8 > 5 so append that to S
So the length of the LIS is 5 (the size of S).
```

Let's take some other sequences to see that this will cover all possible caveats, each presents its own issue

say we have `1,2,3,4,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10`

basically it builds out `12349` first, then `2` will replace `3`, `3` will replace `4`, `4` will replace `9`, then append `5,6,7,8,10` 
so will look like `1,2,2,3,4,6,7,8,10`

take the other case we have `1,2,3,4,5,9,2,10`
this will give us `1,2,2,4,5,9,10`

or take the case we have `1,2,3,4,5,9,6,7,8,10`
this will give us `1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10`

so that kind of illuminates what goes on, in the first case the critical juncture being what happens when you hit the `2` after the `9`, 
how do you deal with these. well the block of `2,3,4` won't do anything really, when you hit `5` you replace the `9` because the `5` and `9` 
are virtually indifferentiable `9` ends the block of the first `5` increasing elements, you replace `9` with `5` because `5` is smaller so there 
is greater potential to hit something > `5` later on. but you only replace the smallest element > itself.  for ex. in the last case, 
if your `6` doesn't replace `9` but instead replaces `1` and `7` replaces `2` and `8` replaces `3`, then we get a final array of 7 elements instead 
of 9. So just do a couple of these and figure out the pattern, this logic isn't the easiest to translate to paper.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very strong relation between LIS and LCS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

This article explains it pretty well I think. Basically the idea is, you can reduce one problem to the other (this is the case in many situations involving Dynamic programming).